# Change variables from Dialog

Tags: java, android

I have a main Activity and a Dialog through which I would like to change some application variables. This unfortunately includes changing the properties of existing instances of several different classes. What I would like to do is call a method of my main Activity that would handle both changing the Activity's variables and modifying existing instances of classes. In my Dialog I call

```
mainActivity.smartSetter(variableName, variableValue);
```

and in my Activity I have

```
public void smartSetter(variableName name, float value) {
    switch (name) {
    case Name1: {do stuff}
    case Name2: {do stuff}
    //etc
}
```

The compiler says that I Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method smartSetter. Being still a Java noob, I suspect it is because the smartSetter needs to be called on an instance of mainActivity, not just the class itself. Could someone please clarify?

Also, this problem seems to be caused by poor design of the application architecture, so I welcome any suggestions that would help me improve the design so that it would be more usable and elegant.

Comment: have you tried it making public static void smartSetter(...){...}??

Comment: What exactly are you referring to with "existing instances of several different classes"? E.g. activities, entity objects etc.? Depending on the answer you can potentially suffice using `startActivityForResult(...)`, or supply a listener interface for a callback, or even create the dialog anonymously inline and have it work on the encapsulating activity's members.

Comment: @Hiral: Then I can't {do stuff} in static context.

Comment: @MH.: Basically I'm modifying properties of running Box2D simulation and its bodies on the fly. As it turns out, tweaking the dialog constructor a little bit might be enough for my concept to work. I will see later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this `smartSetter` should be implemented as a [Broadcast Receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). I think this [example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/) fits your needs.

Comment: I've actually run into that option elsewhere, but was hoping for something quick and simple. Thank you anyway.